# How to send class equals implementation to client using a WCF Web Server

Tags: c#, wcf, webserver, datamember, java-client

I'm developing an aplication in java (JSF) which communicates whith an WCF web server.
I developed the webserver using c#, and I'm havin trouble to send the equals implementation of an complex object to the java client.
For example, consider this c# class:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mywebservice.com/Entidades")]
    public class Record{private Int64 id;
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
          if(obj is Record){
               Record rec = obj as Record;
               return rec.Id == this.Id;
         }
         return false;
    }
```

}

First tryed to put the [DataMember] in the equals, but I discovered that I can't do that.
How is the right way to send this implementation of the "equals" of this complex type to the java client?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What would you expect the XML to look like?

Comment: I was hoping that it was possible to send the equals overload over the xml with the complex types definitions. Something like: <xs:complexType name="TypeDefinition">...Definitions...</xs:complexType>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't make sense.
Web services transfer data, not code.

You need to implement `equals()` in you Java objects in source.

Answer (score 0):

Equals is a method, not a property. As such, I don't know of any way you can simply expose this functionality in the model your service exposes.

Comment: Could expose an operation that takes in two records and returns a bool, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: If the equals method contains a significant amount of business logic, then you could justify adding it as a service method/operation. Either way, the service operations are not part of the model.

Comment: There is significant business logic in the method equals, but I need to reduce as much as I can the traffic between the webserver and the client. I was thinking in send the equals with the complexType definition to reduce the overhead, instead of creating a webserver method. But with a second thought, analyzing yours answers, this really doesn't makes sense